# sqlite python - read records into table from txt file

Tags: python, sqlite

Ive created a python script that sets up a SQLite database and creates a table, now im trying to read values into the table from a .txt file, as follows

```
import  sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE mytable
         (var1 TEXT,
         var2 REAL)''')

c.execute('separator "," ')

c.execute('import records.txt myTable ')

conn.commit()

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM myTable'):
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

the records.txt looks like

```
item1, 8.8
item2, 9.1
```

when i run the python code form the command line i get

```
    c.execute('separator "," ')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "separator": syntax error
```

how do I use the seperator sql statement here and and maybe the same problem will be for the import statement?

How to get this code working?

Comment: Why do you want to import the file using sql commands, while you're in a Python script? Why not just read the file using Python and have it fire a bunch of INSERT statements?

Comment: because if i have var1, var2, ... var1000 then my insert statement with have one thousand ? marks in it

Comment: You could always just generate that SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the Python module `sqlite3`. The `.separator` (for me only with leading dot) command, as well as the `.import`, are features of the CLI fronted `sqlite3`.

If you want to use these, you could use subprocess to invoke the commands:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["sqlite3", "mydatabase.db"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

p.communicate(b"""
CREATE TABLE mytable
         (var1 TEXT,
         var2 REAL);
.separator ","
.import records.txt myTable
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
c.execute('separator "," ')
```

should be replaced with:

```py
sql_statement = ''' INSERT INTO mytable(var1, var2) VALUES (?, ?) '''
values = ('text', 343.4)
c.execute(sql_statement, values)
```

The question marks are the placeholders for the values you want to insert. Note that you should pass these values in a tuple, if you want to insert a single value into your database the values argument should look like this:

```py
values = (text,)
```

A working solution:

```py
import  sqlite3

# create database and initialize cursor
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# create table if not exists
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(var1 TEXT, var2 REAL)''')


sql_insert = ''' INSERT INTO mytable(var1, var2) VALUES (?, ?) '''
with open('results.txt', 'r') as fr:
    for line in fr.readlines():
        # parse the results.txt, create a list of comma separated values
        line = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        t, f = line
        c.execute(sql_insert, (t, float(f)))

conn.commit()

sql_select = ''' SELECT * FROM mytable '''
for row in c.execute(sql_select):
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution above will work fine. Just to make it a little more readable and easier to debug you could also go like this:

```
import  sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE mytable (var1 TEXT, var2 REAL)''')

with open("records.txt", "r") as f:
    rows = f.readlines()
    for row in rows:
        fields = row.split(',')
        c.execute(f'INSERT INTO mytable (var1, var2)'\
                  f"VALUES ('{fields[0]}','{fields[1]}')")

conn.commit()

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM myTable'):
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

This way you open the text file with Python and read the lines. for each line you than seperate the records and put them into the INSERT-statement right away. Quick and easy!

goodluck!

Comment: You are using the non-parametrized version of execute. This is not advisable because it can lead to SQL injection bugs. Also reading a CSV file yourself is cumbersome, use the csv-module. And instead of reading all lines into memory and then iterate, you can directly iterate over the file. And your first f-string is not necessary, you don't expand any variables. Last but not least one would do `var1, var2 = row.split()` instead of accessing `fields[i]`.